# Queue.empty() is false, but the queue size is 0

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, queue

I have a `std::queue<std::vector<char>> GLOB_DATA_QUEUE;` I'm using to tranfer data from one thread to another. I'm having a strange bug when trying to read from the queue. Here's my read code (updated to be completely self-contained):

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>


// global data pipe object instaciation
// queue for data
std::queue<std::vector<char>> GLOB_DATA_QUEUE;
// global mutex for the thread
std::mutex GLOB_MUTEX;
// global condition variable for producer/consumer
std::condition_variable GLOB_CV;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      // flow control for main logic loop
    bool keep_running = true;
    
    // this is the main loop we never plan to exit until shutdown
    while(keep_running)
    {
        
        std::cout<<"servicing data queue"<<std::endl;
        // sensor thread gets prioity, so if we can't have the mutex right now, go do something else
        if(GLOB_MUTEX.try_lock())
        {
            std::cout<<"servicing data queue: got lock"<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"queue size: "<< GLOB_DATA_QUEUE.size() << std::endl;
            
            if(!GLOB_DATA_QUEUE.empty()); // TODO - copy to local variable and release mutex before anything else
            {
                std::cout<<"servicing data queue: pop with queue size: " << GLOB_DATA_QUEUE.size() <<std::endl;
                GLOB_DATA_QUEUE.pop();
            }
            std::cout<<"servicing data queue: unlocking"<<std::endl;
            GLOB_MUTEX.unlock();
                
            // TODO: do something with the data
        }
            
        std::cout<<"finished servicing data queue"<<std::endl;
    
    }
        
        
}
```

During testing I'm running the above periodically without the provider thread running (so nothing is being input into the queue). What seems to happen is that `.empty()` keeps returning false, even when the queue is empty. Here's the output I get:

```
servicing data queue
servicing data queue: got lock
queue size: 0
servicing data queue: pop with queue size: 0
servicing data queue: unlocking
finished servicing data queue
servicing data queue
servicing data queue: got lock
queue size: 4294967295
servicing data queue: pop with queue size: 4294967295
servicing data queue: unlocking
finished servicing data queue
```

After a few repetitions it segfaults. Clearly the issue is calling `.pop()` on an empty queue, however what I can't figure out is why this is happening, and how I can fix it. There're no other threads even running at this point, so nothing else is ever touching the queue, and the mutex is in place at both ends anyway. Any ideas or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are not showing us all the code. In particular `queue size: 0` cannot be printed by the above code.

Comment: Given that you get a segfault every now and then my guess would be that some other thread is updating the queue *without* first acquiring the mutex.

Comment: @MikeVine my mistake, the code and snapshot where taken about 2 minutes apart. I added the additional print statement. Question edited.

Comment: @G.M. I'm quite sure that is not happening.

Comment: Provide a proper [mcve] that both populates (or not) the queue *and* depopulates it, triggering the condition you state.

Comment: I was actually able to reproduce this on MSVC. It also does this with `deque` (the default underlying container)

Comment: @WhozCraig done, question edited. Compiled with g++ with no flags shows the same behaviour.

Comment: Typo: remove the `;` at the end of `if(!GLOB_DATA_QUEUE.empty());` :-)

Comment: @G.M. You, sir, are awesome. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @G.M. noted in comments above, replace

```
if(!GLOB_DATA_QUEUE.empty());
```

with

```
if(!GLOB_DATA_QUEUE.empty())
```

in addition, [add `-Wall` to your compiler flags](https://godbolt.org/z/je9cqbKcc), this is something a compiler can and will catch if you say "please tell me if I'm doing something obviously wrong".

Comment: This. This is it. I have spent all afternoon chasing an ";". Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the problem is not in the code you show us, but in other part of your code - though it's hard to say since you don't include it.

Your third output line, "queue size: 0" is from another part of your code.  So what I think happens, is that after the empty check line, another thread runs and empties the queue without using the mutex.
Thus when this thread gets to the next line, the queue is suddenly empty, since the other thread emptied it between those lines.

Having one part of the code protected by a mutex is of no help unless all code that modifies the same variable is protected by the same mutex.

So go check your other code for where "queue size: 0" is output, and you probably find the cause.

Comment: My mistake; my output snapshot and code where not aligned - the print statement is from this code. Question edited with the correct code aligned with the output snapshot.

Comment: Question now updated with self-contained complete example. Still happens with just the code in the question.